# How to show that a program is being processed?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I made a program on checking if an user-input number is prime or not. However, when I enter large numbers, it takes a considerable amount of time. What sort of code would help to show the user that the number is being checked upon, something similar to a loader, unless the result has been determined? The code is as follows:

```
from math import sqrt as s
from time import time as t
def check_prime(p):
    prime = [p]
    start = t()
    if p > 3:
        for i in range(2, int(s(p)) + 1):
            if p % i == 0:
                end = t()
                print('Time taken is', end - start, 'seconds')
                prime.remove(p)
                break
            else:
                continue
    else:
        pass
    try:
        end
    except:
        end = t()
        print('Time taken is', end - start, 'seconds')
    if p in prime:
        if p == 2 or p == 3 or (p != 1 and p > 0):
            return(f'{p} is a prime number')
        elif p <= 0:
            return(f'{p} is not in the domain of prime or composite numbers')
        else:
            return('1 is neither prime nor composite')
    else:
        return(f'{p} is NOT a prime number')


while True:
    p = input('> ')
    print(check_prime(int(p)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution to get an animated loader (as I guess that's what you asked for) that can be inserted anywhere is something like this:

```
import sys, threading, time

loading = True

def loader(*args):
     while loading:
         time.sleep(0.5)
         sys.stdout.write('[-]' + '\b'*3) # Write loader and return to start of line
         sys.stdout.flush()
         time.sleep(0.5)
         sys.stdout.write('[/]' + '\b'*3)
         sys.stdout.flush()
         time.sleep(0.5)
         sys.stdout.write('[|]' + '\b'*3) 
         sys.stdout.flush()
         time.sleep(0.5)
         sys.stdout.write('[\]' + '\b'*3) 
         sys.stdout.flush()

t = threading.Thread(target=loader)
t.start()

# Do some work here

loading = False
```

To avoid creating a thread, you can do this in your loop while checking if your number is prime.

Answer (score 0):

You could print to the console something like a loading bar( for example, using _ characters ). Therefore, you could add a new '_' char to the console buffer whenever a percentage of the given operations that you perform is being processed.
You could do that in the loop inside the "check_prime" function, as I do not suggest assigning this task to another thread, as there are several situations that you'd have to take into consideration.